# How do I remove the favicons from Google search results?

Tags: google-chrome, browser, google-search, favicon

See the favicons with the red box around them. This is a recent addition and is not caused by anything else as it's a fresh install of chrome.

I would like to disable these.
Is there a setting in Chrome to remove them?

The same search in firefox, for example, doesn't have them, so I assume this is a new chrome thing.

Also, instead of the full URL showing it shows a shortened version. This is something else that has changed recently.

---

[image]

Comment: It's not just in Google Chrome, it will happen on any browser once you sign into your Google Account.

Comment: In the last while for me, the favicons have disappeared even though I am always logged into my google account to ensure my settings are backed up. Can any of you verify that? It could be something regional if you are still experiencing it Macondo

Answer (score 3):

It appears that the only solution for now is to filter out those icons using adblock extension of your choice (uBlock Origin, Adblock/Adblock Plus, etc). Signing out of your Google account does not help anymore.

The below filter applied in uBlock Origin works for `google.com`:

```
google.com##.xA33Gc
```

Comment: This looks like it works for now. These rudy things were gone for the last two weeks or so but they have resurfaced today. I'll not mark this as a solution as yet because this could be subject to change but for now, it does, so thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Add those codes into your installed/favorite adblock extension:

```
google.com##.TbwUpd
google.com##.yWc32e
google.com##.ab_ctl
google.com##.fl
```

Remove google.com##.fl if you dont want keep translate this page URL

change google.com if you using google in your country as like I am using Google Norway.

```
google.no##.TbwUpd
google.no##.yWc32e
google.no##.ab_ctl
google.no##.fl
```

Comment: I don't want to use an extension, although these favicons have gone for now. Thanks for your input.

Comment: While it does remove the favicon, this also remove the website name, which is inconvenient

Comment: These favicons came back today. So I did try this but as @Richard says it will remove the URLs also. The one UnclickableCharacter gave works (for now at least).